# Android activity from background restore is incorrect

Tags: android

I have the following flow in my application:

```
SignInActivity (MAIN) -> Android Browser (for OAuth) -> OAuth Activity ->
    -> PinCode Activity -> SignInActivity -> AccountActivity
```

Flag `NoHistory = True` for all activities.

In my testing, I see that when I am at the `AccountActivity` and I send the app to background (by clicking on the home button), the app resumes back with the `OAuth Activity`. This is incredibly disturbing because the `OAuth` flow finishes right after the `PinCode` flow is triggered. Like:

```
try
{
    Server.FinalOAuthChallenge(...) // blocking API
    ...
    GoToPinCodeSetupActivity();
    Intent startPinFlow = new Intent(this, typeof(PinCodeActivity));
    startPinFlow.PutExtra(SKConstants.SKPinCodeIntentArgumentIsStartKey, true);
    startPinFlow.PutExtra(SKConstants.SKPinCodeIntentArgumentTypeKey, (int)PinCodeActivity.Type.Set);
    StartActivity(startPinFlow);
    Finish();
}
```

Every time the application starts from the background, it actually starts this `OAuth Activity`. It's also weird because I have already set the `NoHistory` flag to true.

---

Here's how I create my browser intent:

```
Intent oauthIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
oauthIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
oauthIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
activity.StartActivity(oauthIntent);
```

Here's my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.alpha.romeo" android:versionName="1.1.3" android:versionCode="9">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <application android:name="AlphaRomeo.SKApplication" android:label="AlphaRomeo" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:label="@string/appName" android:name="AlphaRomeo.SignInActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation" android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ALPHAROMEO" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.ALPHAROMEO" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.ALPHAROMEO" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ALPHAROMEO" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ALPHAROMEO" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ALPHAROMEO" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ALPHAROMEO" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.ALPHAROMEO" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.ALPHAROMEO" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ALPHAROMEO" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ALPHAROMEO" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ALPHAROMEO" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ALPHAROMEO" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.ALPHAROMEO" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.ALPHAROMEO" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ALPHAROMEO" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ALPHAROMEO" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ALPHAROMEO" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="AlphaRomeo.OAuthActivity" android:label="@string/appName">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="com.alpha.romeo" android:host="oauth" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: What happen after removing `NoHistory = True` for all Activities ?

Comment: Oh no; that's a recipe for disaster. Please don't make me do that. The logic is too constrained for that to work I'm afraid. It's an existing code base that I have developed on. :(

Comment: i am not saying do that. before fixing any issue we must know the behaviors of Application or why issue is occurring. posted problem looks occurring due to Activities launch mode,NoHistory flags or probably calling `finish` in Activities.

Comment: Ok, let me pull some strings.

Comment: Also, just wanna point out that this does not happen on the Android simulator. It's only on the device.

Comment: I guess this could be because you have started Auth activity in a new task and all the subsiquest activity will be in the same task and when we start AccountActivity with noHistory flag then when we go to background it will call finish method of this activity hence this is not comming back, I guess you can solve the problem by removing noHistory just from AccountActivity (If it does not affect your business use cases)

Comment: Update: removed `NoHistory` from everywhere; removed `Finish()` wherever applicable to run the main flow. Backgrounding works perfectly. Some other flows might be broken but it confirms your suspicion.

Comment: Guys thank you. Removing `NoHistory` flag from `AccountActivity` works. Please answer below so I can accept it. Thanks!